# Aeron getting rates from CME UDP multicast using RateSubscriber.cpp

Tags: c++, udp, aeron

I can easily get rates from the New release UDP stream using winsockets, but for some reason I can't get any rates using aeron. I am using the RateSubscriber project and the following URI:

```
const static std::string DEFAULT_CHANNEL = "aeron:udp?endpoint=224.0.28.1:14310";
```

When I run my code (after I started aeronmd.exe of course) I dont receive any rates:

```
Subscribing to channel aeron:udp?endpoint=224.0.28.1:14310 on Stream ID 10
Subscription: aeron:udp?endpoint=224.0.28.1:14310 22:10
0 msgs/sec, 0 bytes/sec, totals 0 messages 0 MB payloads
0 msgs/sec, 0 bytes/sec, totals 0 messages 0 MB payloads
0 msgs/sec, 0 bytes/sec, totals 0 messages 0 MB payloads
0 msgs/sec, 0 bytes/sec, totals 0 messages 0 MB payloads
Shutting down...
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to run something else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For Aeron to subscribe to a multicast publication then you need to specify the interface in the URI in addition to endpoint. Also, are you sure the published data is using the Aeron transport protocol?

Comment: Thanks Martin for the quick reply. I also tried to use:
const static std::string DEFAULT_CHANNEL = "aeron:udp?endpoint=224.0.28.1:14310|interface=localhost"; with the same result. The USD endpoint I use is the standard CME address they give in their config.xml. How can I "wrap" that CME stream in an Aeron transport protocol? Should I first create a publisher that reads the CME stream, wraps it in an AERON stream and then read it in my subscriber?

Comment: What config.xml? If you are talking about CME market data then this is not Aeron.

Comment: The interface URI param for Aeron should be the local interface address you wish to listen on. However, I believe this is separate to the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks Martin. I think I misunderstood the purpose of Aeron. I assumed that the CME was delivering the packets in a ready for Aeron to use format and that the "publication app" was the CME, not just an IPC. Is that correct?

Comment: You should contact your account manager at the CME and discuss how it works. Aeron is a message transport independent from the CME.